ADF - Sharepoint Online List connection issue
I am trying to set up a connection between ADF and Sharepoint so that I can use ADF pipelines to get data from a sharepoint online list.
Though, I have encountered some issue, the instructions I have found on the internet are unclear.
The issue is related to URL, I am not sure what exact URL I should provide in the following fields:

Microsoft Entra ID:

redirect URL when registering an app


Sharepoint Online when giving permission to acces SP site:

App Domain
Redirect URL



So far I skipped providing a redirect URL in app registration (in Azure).
In sharepoint I typed:
App domain: localhost.com
Redirect URL: https://localhost.com
If my understanding is correct, when providing permission in sharepoint I should provide the following:

App domain: .sharepoint.com
Redirect URL: URL where sharepoint list is located (?) or should it be a direct link to the list (?)

In the Azure registered app, I have no clue what redirect URL I should provide..
Could anybody please direct me?

There is no need to provide redirect URL when registering an app. and when you give permissions to app on your share point site you can use the values provided in Microsoft document and doesn't necessarily need reality or with the official domain of your organization/site.
App Domain:  contoso.com 

Redirect URL:  https://www.contoso.com

Or you can Provide
App Domain  : <oragnization>.sharepoint.com  

Redirect URL :  https://<oraganization>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/Lists/<list_name>/AllItems.aspx
(Go to your sharepoint site and go to your list and give the URL ogf that page as shown in below image)


